# How to host an htm5 app on a private channel on "Roku"?

Tags: html, roku, brightscript

I am just starting with development  for "Roku". I want to know **How can I host an html5 app on private channel on Roku**. To get started I have created a a private roku channel from https://www.instanttvchannel.com and have even installed on my roku device.

My actual target is to **host/launch an HTML5 app on my private channel**, Is there any way I can acheive that. I have downloaded the sdk and I have found that it uses **BrightScript for programming**. On the www.instanttvchannel.com I can only find the options for audio,video  ,movies etc. But I want to launch an HTML5 app.

Any suggestion that could suggest me or atleast point me in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML code can not be used in roku app.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no HTML support on Roku platform, there is no web browser to be used.